# Is it possible to display an action bar back button instead of the up button?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a UI sub flow in my application, and I would like to provide forward and back navigation controls on the action bar. Note I said back navigation, not 'up'.

I am aware of the up navigation button feature in Android. In this section of my UI I would like to replace the up button with a back button (and it's icon).

My question is, how do I override the UI of the up button to display a back button instead?

Note I am talking about the UI here. The navigation behavior is easy to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about ActionBarSherlock (ABS)? Reason why I ask is, that ABS is quite close to the native implementation and once you have downloaded that source code you can find out a lot of interesting things. Searching for the home button (in the *drawable* folders) shows that the icon is named `abs__ic_ab_back_holo_light.png`.

Searching for that name leads to `<homeAsUpIndicator>@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_holo_light<homeAsUpIndicator>` in the `Theme.Sherlock.Light`. So what does it mean? For ABS you could derive a new theme and overlay the *homeAsUpIndicator* tag using your own drawable.

And how about the native Android scheme? Most likely just the same tag to overwrite. If you don't use ABS derive from a standard theme.

Example: here I have redefined the up indicator (with ABS)

> ```
> <style name="MyAppStyle" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
>     <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/new_indicator</item>
>     <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/new_indicator</item>
> ```

Hope that helps! Cheers ....